# Twitter Bootstrap button dropdown not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, button, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

**UPDATE:** Ok, I found the cause. The grey area where the button resides is a div for the navigation. It has fixed position and a high z-index to make it float above other elements. This is what's causing the problem. If I remove the z-index of the parent DIV, it works fine. But I can't do that because the other elements will then overlap the fixed navigation div.

**How it's Supposed to Look like (FIREFOX)**

[image: How it's Supposed to Look like (FIREFOX)]

**How it is rendered in IE (9)**

[image: How it is rendered in IE (9)]

Full Code:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large dropdown-toggle" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top:15px" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Hi @User.Identity.Name!
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Lab")">Open the Lab</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/LogOff">Log-out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone got any ideas or workarounds/overrides I need to put in the CSS to cover this problem?

Comment: Looks like it could be z-index related. Have you tried explicitly adding a z-index to the `dropdown-menu` list and/or list items?

Comment: Try add `z-index: 99999;` and check result.

Comment: yep, tried those but they don't work. appreciate your replies though! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu{
z-index:99;
}
```

Should do the trick...Though depending on the version of IE there are some caveats.

Comment: Appreciate the answer but I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I feel that this isn't a CSS problem, more of a javascript problem with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't of any help. Can you post the page's link so I can look directly at the code and see what else is influencing the problem?

Comment: No worries, really appreciate your inputs! We haven't published it yet, it's all in my local, sorry. I'll let you know once we have it online. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with bootstrap 3. Removing the filter property from the .navbar class worked for me.

```
.navbar {
  /*filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff8f8f8', GradientType=0);*/
}
```